# Pykka: How to cancel an actor's pending messages queue when it has been stopped

Tags: python, concurrency, actor, pykka

I've playing with [Pykka](http://www.pykka.org) actors library and I came up with the following awesome silly example:

```
import pykka
from time import sleep

class TestActor(pykka.ThreadingActor):
    def on_receive(self, message):
        sleep(1)
        print(message["v"])    

a = TestActor.start()
for i in xrange(10):
    print("asking for " + str(i))
    a.tell({"v":i})
print(a.stop())
```

I get the expected result: 10 *asking for* lines which are printed immediately and another 10 lines each printed in 1 second time period:

```
asking for 0
asking for 1
asking for 2
asking for 3
asking for 4
asking for 5
asking for 6
asking for 7
asking for 8
asking for 9
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
True
```

After all the requests have been served by the actor, `True` is printed as the result of the `stop` action.

**I wonder if it would be possible to stop the actor thus cancelling the reception and processing of the reamining messages.**

[I've checked the library documentation](https://www.pykka.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=stop#pykka.ActorRef.stop) but all I can find is the `block` stop parameter which means a quite different thing: When set to `False` it makes the call to be asynchronous but its behaviour concerning the message queue is the same:

> **stop(block=True, timeout=None)**
>
> Send a message to the actor, asking it
>   to stop.
>
> Returns True if actor is stopped or was being stopped at the time of
>   the call. False if actor was already dead. If block is False, it
>   returns a future wrapping the result.
>
> Messages sent to the actor before the actor is asked to stop will be
>   processed normally before it stops.
>
> Messages sent to the actor after the actor is asked to stop will be
>   replied to with pykka.ActorDeadError after it stops.
>
> The actor may not be restarted.
>
> block and timeout works as for ask().
>
> Returns:  pykka.Future, or a boolean result if blocking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pykka does not currently (1.2.0) support interrupting the message queue.

Source: https://github.com/jodal/pykka/issues/46